# How do I write an if then for a boolean variable in a shell script?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to write a simple shell script to hide/show my desktop icons but I get the error "hidedesktopicons.sh: line 1: [[gsettings: command not found" when I try to run it?

I searched for how to use if then statements in a shell script. I added "fi"

```
enter code here

cat hidedesktopicons.sh 
if [[gsettings get org.mate.background show-desktop-icons = true]]
then gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons false
else gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons true
fi
```

I expect the icons to hide/unhide. I get the error "hidedesktopicons.sh: line 1: [[gsettings: command not found"

Comment: `if gsettings get org.mate.background show-desktop-icons; then ...; else ...; fi`

Comment: `gsettings` almost certainly outputs the literal string `true`, rather than have a zero exit status.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The immediate problem is that you need whitespace after `[[`:

```
if [[ gsettings ...
```

The *next* problem is that you need to use a command substitution to capture the output of `gsettings` so that you can compare it to `true`:

```
if [[ $(gsettings get org.mate.background show-desktop-icons) = true ]]
then gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons false
else gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons true
fi
```

You might want to define a pair of functions to reduce some of the repetitiveness of this code:

```
get_icon_status () {
  gsettings get org.mate.background show-desktop-icons
}

set_icon_status () {
  gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons "$1"
}

if [[ $(get_icon_status) = true ]]; then
  set_icon_status false
else
  set_icon_status true
fi
```

Comment: Sincere thanks. The first bit needed a white space after as well. It runs with no errors but nothing happens to the icons? The if then statement is executing. After modifying like so: if [[ $(gsettings get org.mate.background show-desktop-icons) = true ]]
then gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons false;
echo "1";
else gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons true;
echo "2";
fi I get alternating 1 and 2 on the command line but the icons do not change?

Comment: Ok. I think its something with the actual command. If I run a script with only "gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons false;" nothing happens, but if I run the same command from the terminal it works. Somehow this command does not work from within a script?

Comment: Ok after an hour of trying to understand which shebang I realised that my error was simply not to run with "sudo". @chepner you beauty thanks again.

Comment: You  are missing a space after true in your first if statement

Answer (score 0):

Bash, in contrast to common programming languages, does not really have keywords for `true` and `false`. So if a program returns in a terminal the string value "true" it will just consider it to be a string of the same nature as 'foo" or "bar".  The `if`-statement in bash does not evaluate what is returned by a command, it evaluates the return-code of a command.

```
if list1; then list2; else list3; fi
```

Which should be read as: *if `list1` is executed and has a return-code 0, it will execute `list2`, otherwise `list3`.*

To fully demonstrate I use the following confusing command:

```
$ if echo true; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
true
yes
$ if echo false; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
false
yes
```

As you see, `echo true` returns the value `true` and `echo false` the value `false` but both return `yes` which just indicates that the `echo` command executed successfully. If we know make use of the binaries `true` and `false`

```
$ which true; true; echo $?
/usr/bin/true
0
$ if true; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
yes
$ which false; false; echo $?
/usr/bin/false
1
$ if false; then echo yes; else echo no; fi
no
```

One of the common commands used in the if-statement is the `test` command, commonly written as `[ EXPRESSION ]` or the bash compound command `[[ EXPRESSION ]]` , both having a return code of 0 if `EXPRESSION` evaluates to true, and 1 if `EXPRESSION` is false. These commands can be used to do string evaluations as presented by the OP.

```
if [[ $(gsettings get org.mate.background show-desktop-icons) == true ]]
then gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons false
else gsettings set org.mate.background show-desktop-icons true
fi
```

Comment: `$ if echo true; then echo yes; else echo no; fi` should write `true\nyes\n`, not just `yes\n`